# Read/Write Memory-Mapped File in R

Tags: r, mmap, memory-mapping

I'm trying to control a digital-to-analog converter entirely from R - if it is even possible.

The source code I have from the device appears to be writing specific bytes to a memory-mapped file, so I figured I would use the mmap pack and attempt to do the same.

Is this the correct approach? I.e. can I duplicate this c# code by simply writing to a memory-mapped file - in this case, "EECI_DAC8U10_IN"

Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles

Public Class Form1
    'Load DAC-8U10 device driver before running this example
    'This is the most simple example which sets the analog level on channel 1 and generates an error message if the DAC-8U10 device driver is not loaded

```
Dim mask, bit, X As Integer
Dim relayByte = New Byte(30) {}

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Label6.Text = Str(Int(Val(TextBox3.Text) / 4))                  'show MS byte
    Label7.Text = Str(Val(TextBox3.Text) - (Val(Label6.Text) * 4))  'show LS byte

    relayByte(3) = Val(Label6.Text)     'store MS byte
    relayByte(4) = Val(Label7.Text)     'store LS byte
    SetOutput() 'set 
End Sub

Private Sub SetOutput()         'this is the single line of code needed to set all 8 analog levels on the DAC-8U10
    Try
        MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("EECI_DAC8U10_IN").CreateViewAccessor(0, relayByte.Length).WriteArray(Of Byte)(0, relayByte, 0, relayByte.Length)     'send byte array to DAC-8U10 device driver
    Catch noFile As FileNotFoundException
        MsgBox("No Data - Please load DAC-8U10 Driver", , "System Message")  'put code here to autostart software interface
        End
    Catch Ex As Exception
        MsgBox(Ex.GetType.ToString, , "System Message")
        End
        'exception code can go here
    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: What do you mean by "controlling from R" ?

Comment: Are you asking somebody to translate that code (or similar enough) into R?

Comment: The question is whether this is the correct approach? Could you try an edit your question to be more clear from a reader's point of view?

Comment: @Chelmy88 , by writing data to the device. Changing byte(1) = 200 will change the mA output of the physical device accordingly.

Comment: @CeliusStingher, Yes, that is correct. Is the c# code simply loading and editing a memory-mapped file?